# NextJS server does not save cookies from NestJS server

Tags: next.js, cookies, nestjs, next.js13, server-action

the NestJS server has an endpoint for logging in and registering to the system, after which two tokens are generated: accessToken and refreshToken

```
//Auth endpoints
response.cookie(AuthConstants.REFRESH_TOKEN, data.refreshToken, {
  httpOnly: true,
  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 15,
  sameSite: 'strict',
  secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
})
```

refresh token is saved in server cookies

Previously, I performed registration and login on the client side, but now with the advent of server actions in nextjs I started using it

```
// Server action
"use server"

export const loginAction = async(formData: FormData) => {
  const email = formData.get("email") as string

  const password = formData.get("password") as string

  try {
    return await authService.login({email, password})
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

```
//Auth service
class AuthService {
  login () {...}
}

export const authService = new AuthService()
```

when the login was on the client, then in the browser in the Application tab, I always saw this refreshToken, and at any time I could use it to get a session from the server, but now this refreshToken is not saved and I cannot get the session itself